# CakePHP 3 - Problema com Nested Eager Loading

Tags: cakephp, orm

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

- Users
- Tools
- Groups

Todas elas tem associação de many to many

E eu já possuo as pivot tables:

- groups_tools
- groups_users
- tools_users

Estou tentando fazer a seguinte query:

```
TableRegistry::get('Users')
               ->find()
               ->where(['id' => 1])
               ->contain(['Groups.Tools'])
               ->first();
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro

**Groups is not associated with Tools**

Porém, creio que estou seguindo todas as convenções.

```
class GroupsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsToMany('Tools');
        $this->belongsToMany('Users');
    }
}

class ToolsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsToMany('Users');
        $this->belongsToMany('Groups');
    }
}

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsToMany('Tools');
        $this->belongsToMany('Groups');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema, como eu estava criando um plugin, as relações entre tabelas precisam conter o namespace do plugin:

```
class GroupsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsToMany('SeuPlugin.Tools');
        $this->belongsToMany('SeuPlugin.Users');
    }
}

class ToolsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsToMany('SeuPlugin.Users');
        $this->belongsToMany('SeuPlugin.Groups');
    }
}

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {  
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsToMany('SeuPlugin.Tools');
        $this->belongsToMany('SeuPlugin.Groups');
    }
}
```